How to dynamically create a nested tree view structure using RecyclerView in Android?
I am working on an Android application where I need to create a tree view structure using RecyclerView. Currently, I have a RecyclerView item that contains another RecyclerView, and based on user interaction, the nested RecyclerView will be visible or hidden. I need to repeat the same behavior for individual sub-items if they contain any children.
However, after making an API call, I don't know how many children each individual sub-list item can contain. I need to represent these children under their respective parent items, similar to the example image below.
Android TreeView
If we know the number of children, we can manually set that many child adapters. But in this case, I don't know the number of children available for each sub-diagnosis. Is there any way to use a single item layout and dynamically set the children based on their availability?

Your problem is not clear. Please edit your question and post the code and indicate where in the code you aren't sure about what to do.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

{
"message": "Request completed successfully",
"data": {
"conceptCategory": "Others",
"conceptCategoryId": 0,
"diagnoses": [
{
"children": [
{
"children": [
{
"children": null
}}}]}}
this is how I'm getting response after making an api call, I need to show diagnoses as a main category and every children's comes under treeview under it's parent, but I every diagnoses have multiple children's or sometimes none, based on this response I need to create a treeview using recyclerview.
